# Calculating the average of numbers

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="Demonstrates some logic errors" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, average, errors" />
  <title>Average numbers</title>
  <script src="badaverage.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Average numbers</h1>
    <p>Click the button to enter a series of numbers to average</p>
    <button id="enter">Enter your first number</button>
    <p><span id="numberList"></span></p>
    <button id="calculate">Calculate the average</button>
    <p><span id="result"></span></p>

</body>
</html>

/*
   JavaScript used with 'average.html'
   Use an interactive debugger to find the errors in the JavaScript below
*/

"use strict";
//Global variables accessible to all functions
var numbers = [];  //create an empty array
var enterButton = null;  //global variables must be initialised
var calculateButton = null;

/* Get a number from the prompt
*  If a valid number add to array, if not give error message to user
*  Display the updated array of numbers on the web page
*  Make the Calculate button visible
*/
function enterNumber(){
    var number = prompt("Enter your number");
    var number = Number(number);   //WHAT DOES THIS LINE DO?
    if (number >= 0) {    // test what is entered is a number   
        numbers.push(number);   //add the number entered to the end of the array 
    }
    else{
        alert("Please enter a valid number");
    }
    document.getElementById("numberList").innerHTML = "The numbers you have entered so far are: " + numbers;  //diplay a list of number entered
    enterButton.textContent = "Enter your next number"; //change the label on the Enter Button
    calculateButton.style.visibility = "visible";     //show the button  - uses the CSS property of the elenment
}       
/* Calculate the sum and average of the array of number
*  Display the results on the web page
*/
function calculateAverage(){
    var average = 0;
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0 ; i <= numbers.length; i++){    
        total = numbers[i];   //add the each number in the array to the cumulative total 
    }
    average = total/i;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The total of your numbers is " + total + " and their average is " + average;
}

function init(){
        enterButton = document.getElementById("enter");  
        calculateButton = document.getElementById("calculate");
        calculateButton.style.visibility = "hidden";    //hide the Calculate button until some numbers are entered
        enterButton.onclick = enterNumber;
        calculateButton.onclick = calculateAverage;
}

window.onload = init;
```

Everything looks like it works in my code expect on line 33 in my JavaScript the 'function calculateAverage' doesn't seem to work properly, when I click the button to calculate the average I get 'NaN' as my result, I am not sure how I can fix this so some help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating the numbers for 1 more iteration as compared to the number of items in array `numbers`. Update it to: `for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {`. The reason of your problem is, when you access `numbers[numbers.length]`, the value is `undefined`, and `undefined/numbers.length` is NaN.

And, you need to add new numbers to the total: `total += numbers[i];`

```js
/*
   JavaScript used with 'average.html'
   Use an interactive debugger to find the errors in the JavaScript below
*/

"use strict";
//Global variables accessible to all functions
var numbers = []; //create an empty array
var enterButton = null; //global variables must be initialised
var calculateButton = null;

/* Get a number from the prompt
 *  If a valid number add to array, if not give error message to user
 *  Display the updated array of numbers on the web page
 *  Make the Calculate button visible
 */
function enterNumber() {
  var number = prompt("Enter your number");
  var number = Number(number); //WHAT DOES THIS LINE DO?
  if (number >= 0) { // test what is entered is a number   
    numbers.push(number); //add the number entered to the end of the array 
  } else {
    alert("Please enter a valid number");
  }
  document.getElementById("numberList").innerHTML = "The numbers you have entered so far are: " + numbers; //diplay a list of number entered
  enterButton.textContent = "Enter your next number"; //change the label on the Enter Button
  calculateButton.style.visibility = "visible"; //show the button  - uses the CSS property of the elenment
}
/* Calculate the sum and average of the array of number
 *  Display the results on the web page
 */
function calculateAverage() {
  var average = 0;
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    total += numbers[i]; //add the each number in the array to the cumulative total 
  }
  average = total / i;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The total of your numbers is " + total + " and their average is " + average;
}

function init() {
  enterButton = document.getElementById("enter");
  calculateButton = document.getElementById("calculate");
  calculateButton.style.visibility = "hidden"; //hide the Calculate button until some numbers are entered
  enterButton.onclick = enterNumber;
  calculateButton.onclick = calculateAverage;
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="Demonstrates some logic errors" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, average, errors" />
  <title>Average numbers</title>
  <script src="badaverage.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Average numbers</h1>
  <p>Click the button to enter a series of numbers to average</p>
  <button id="enter">Enter your first number</button>
  <p><span id="numberList"></span></p>
  <button id="calculate">Calculate the average</button>
  <p><span id="result"></span></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changes made:

1. In the loop changed `i<=numbers.length` to `i<numbers.length`.

**Updated `calculateAverage` function**

```
function calculateAverage(){
    var average = 0;
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0 ; i < numbers.length; i++){    
        total += numbers[i];   //add the each number in the array to the cumulative total 
    }

    average = total/i;

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The total of your numbers is " + total + " and their average is " + average;
}
```

Comment: Your total value is not getting updated. It should be `total += numbers[i]`.