# How to calculate avg dynamically and flexibly in html+js?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to receive data from the user. 
I want to make it possible for the user to add or delete buttons.
And I want to average the results entered by the user.
How can I know how many buttons a user has created?
How do I know the average of the values entered by the user?

```
<form>
   <div id="box">
   <input type="text" class="sj"> <input type="button" value="add" onclick="add_textbox()">
   </div>
</form>

<script>
        const add_textbox = () => {
            
            const box = document.getElementById("box");
            const newP = document.createElement('p');
            newP.innerHTML = "<input type='text'> <input type='button' value='delete' onclick='remove(this)'>";
            box.appendChild(newP);
        }
        const remove = (obj) => {
            document.getElementById('box').removeChild(obj.parentNode);

        }
</script>
```

Comment: add a common class to all the textboxes. Get all the textboxes using queryByClassName methods, iterate and average

Comment: You create a counter that will increase each time a button is created, as well as the variable that will get the sum of his values, and divide it with counter

Comment: Took me one search. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46251674/calculating-the-average-of-numbers

Answer (score 0):

```js
const add_textbox = () => {
            
            const box = document.getElementById("box");
            const newP = document.createElement('p');
            newP.innerHTML = "<input type='number' class='sj'> <input type='button' value='delete' onclick='remove(this)'>";
            box.appendChild(newP);
        }
        const remove = (obj) => {
            document.getElementById('box').removeChild(obj.parentNode);

        }
const resultButton = document.querySelector('[data-button-result]');

 const getResult = () => {
   const result = [...document.querySelectorAll('.sj')].reduce((acc, input) => {
   if (input.valueAsNumber)
     return acc += input.valueAsNumber
     
   else return acc
   }, 0)
   const resultElement = document.querySelector('[data-result]');
   resultElement.innerText = result
 }

resultButton.addEventListener('click', getResult)
```

```html
<form>
   <div id="box">
   <input type="number" class="sj"> <input type="button" value="add" onclick="add_textbox()">
   </div>
</form>
   <button data-button-result>Get results</button>
   <div data-result></div>
```

Comment: Still needs the number of buttons, tho.

Comment: He can use my code to get button number, that's much easier.